# OpenCV trace contours tracing whole image as largest contour?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to generate a dataset for training a neural network, and this requires me to crop around a moving object (snail) in multiple frames of a video.

I have split up the video into frames and used OpenCV to crop around the object by using HSV thresholding and contour tracing like so:

```
import cv2 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("./pngs/04Feb21_1_crop/20000.png")
img_edit = cv2.imread("./pngs/04Feb21_1_crop/20000.png")

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_edit, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
plt.imshow(hsv_img) ## 1
```

[image: hsv_img]

```
low = np.array([99, 109, 77] )
high = np.array([115, 255, 255])
curr_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, low, high)
hsv_img[curr_mask > 0] = ([84, 255, 200])

# converting the hsv image to gray in order to be able to apply
# contouring
RGB_again = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(RGB_again, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 90, 255, 0)
plt.imshow(threshold, cmap="binary")
```

[image]

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
threshold = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
threshold = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

contours, hierarchy =  cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img_edit = cv2.drawContours(img_edit, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
plt.imshow(img_edit)
```

[image: traced contours]

As you can see here, the green line on the bottom indicates that there's some contour that includes the bottom edge of the photo. Therefore, when I select the largest contour and crop around it, like so:

```
# find largest contour
areaArray = []
count = 1

for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    areaArray.append(area)

#first sort the array by area
sorteddata = sorted(zip(areaArray, contours), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

#find the nth largest contour [n-1][1], in this case 2
largestcontour = sorteddata[0][1]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(largestcontour)
crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
plt.imshow(crop)
```

[image]

The entire image is cropped, because the bounding rectangle of the largest contour is essentially the size of the image.

I have been circumventing this by selecting the second largest contour, but it doesn't work for all my frames. For example, in this frame, selecting the second largest contour like so:

```
secondlargestcontour = sorteddata[1][1]
```

And cropping as before yields this grey area:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong with the HSV thresholding? Is it because the object itself is not distinct enough from the shadows/reflections of the water?

Any and all help is really appreciated. I am a Python and OpenCV newbie and if there is something very obvious that I am missing, I apologize in advance.

The original image used for all of the code is here:
[image: original_pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing the lower and higher boundary of HSV solve your problem.

I have changed values to this

```py
low = np.array([0, 35, 0])
high = np.array([253, 255, 255])
```

---

test code

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("image.png")
HSV = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

low = np.array([0, 35, 0])
high = np.array([253, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(HSV, low, high)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_contour = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

largestcontour = sorted_contour[0]
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largestcontour)
crop = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow("crop", crop)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output:

| mask image | result image | crop image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: mask] | [image: result] | [image] |